# is performance of sql insert dependent on number of rows in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to log some information from the users of a system to a special statistics table.
There will be a lot of inserts into this table, but no reads (not for the users, only I will read)

Will I get a better performance to have two tables where I move the rows into a table I can use for querying, just to keep the "insert" table as small as possible?

E.g. I the user-behavior results in 20000 inserts per day, the table will grow rapidly, and I am afraid the inserts get slower and slower as more and more rows are inserted.

Comment: If you have indexes on the table, these need to be updated on every insert. The more rows, the more performance needed.

Comment: @juergend If users aren't reading the table, there's no need to have indexes on it.

Comment: @JeffRosenberg: Well, but that will be a problem pretty soon. 20k rows every day - after a month you will wait a long time for your select query without indexes.

Comment: @juergend Fair enough. My impression is that in this case, the need for fast inserts vastly outweighs the need for selects, but I guess I don't really know that for sure. If the table is being queried very rarely, leaving off the indexes could be a cheap and easy way to fix the problem. If it's being queried on a regular basis, that might not be an option.

Comment: Dont care about the reading :) All I want is fast insert!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserts get slower if SQL Server has to update indexes. If your indexes mean reorganisation isn't required then inserts won't be particularly slow even for large amounts of data.

I don't think you should prematurely optimise in the way you're suggesting unless you're totally sure it's necessary. Most likely you're fine just taking a simple approach, then possibly adding a periodically-updated stats table for querying if you don't mind that being somewhat out of date ... or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of the inserts depends on whether there are indexes on the table. You say that users aren't going to be reading from the table. If you yourself only need to query it rarely, then you could just leave off the indexes entirely, in which case insert performance won't change.

If you do need indexes on the table, you're right that performance will start to suffer. In this case, you should look into partitioning the table and performing minimally-logged inserts. That's done by inserting the new records into a new table that has the same structure as your main table but without indexes on it. Then, once the data has been inserted, adding it to the main table becomes nothing more than a metadata operation; you simply redefine that table as a new partition of your main table.

[Here's a good writeup on table partitioning](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/).